# Pasting data into a DataGridView vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, copy-paste

So this morning I ran into a wall:

Using this Code I randomly get another row to show up when i paste my data.

It is meant to receive values ranging from 1 to 99999

So when i copy this:

[image]

And paste it into the Program this happens:

[image]

```
    Private Sub DataGridView101_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView101.KeyDown

    If e.Control And
       e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then

        IsCopyPaste = True
        Dim _ClipboardRows As String() = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText().Split({System.Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)


        Me.DataGridView101.BeginEdit(True)

        For Each _ClipboardRow As String In _ClipboardRows
            If _ClipboardRow <> "" Then

                Dim _CellL As String = ""
                Dim _CellR As String = ""

                For Each _ClipboardColumn As String In _ClipboardRow.Split(System.Convert.ToChar(vbTab))

                    If _CellL = "" Then
                        _CellL = _ClipboardColumn
                    Else
                        If _CellR = "" Then
                            _CellR = _ClipboardColumn
                        End If
                    End If

                Next

                Dim _DataRow As System.Data.DataRow = (CType(Me.DataGridView101.DataSource, System.Data.DataTable)).NewRow()

                _DataRow("1") = _CellL
                _DataRow("2") = _CellR

                CType(Me.DataGridView101.DataSource, System.Data.DataTable).Rows.Add(_DataRow)

            End If

        Next

        Me.DataGridView101.EndEdit()
        CType(Me.DataGridView101.DataSource, System.Data.DataTable).AcceptChanges()

        IsCopyPaste = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution for that. You must call the functions from your event. In my application I need to decide allow pasting or not in the PasteUnboundRecords sub, which is controlled by the Allowed boolen

```
Public Sub CopyRows(MyDataGridView As DataGridView)
    Dim d As DataObject = MyDataGridview.GetClipboardContent()
    Try
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(d)
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("Text not copied, null value")
    End Try
End Sub

Sub PasteUnboundRecords(MyDataGridView As DataGridView)
    Dim Allowed As Boolean      
    Dim OriginLines As String() = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text).Split(New String(0) {vbCr & vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Dim Xo As Integer = SelectedAreaMinColumn(MyDataGridview)
    Dim Yo As Integer = SelectedAreaMinRow(MyDataGridview)
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim Y As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ii As Integer
    Dim jj As Integer = 0
    Dim m1 As Integer
    Dim n1 As Integer = OriginLines.Length  
    Dim m2 As Integer = SelectedAreaColumns(MyDataGridView)
    Dim n2 As Integer = SelectedAreaRows(MyDataGridview)
    Dim m2Max As Integer = MyDataGridview.Columns.Count
    Dim n2Max As Integer = MyDataGridview.Rows.Count

    For j = 0 To Math.Max(n1-1, n2-1)
        Y = Yo + j
        If Y = n2Max Then Exit For
        If j-jj*n1 = n1 Then jj = jj+1
        Dim OriginValue As String() = OriginLines(j-jj*n1).Split(New String(0) {vbTab}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        m1 = OriginValue.Length
        ii = 0
        For i = 0 To Math.Max(m1-1, m2-1)
            X = Xo + i
            If X = m2Max Then Exit For
            If i-ii*m1 = m1 Then ii = ii+1
            If X > 0 Then 'Avoid pasting in first column containing codes
                If Y = 0 Then 'Avoid first line
                    Allowed = True
                Else 'Check DataValidatios
                    If DataValidations(OriginValue(i-ii*m1), X) = "OK" Then
                        Allowed = True
                    Else
                        Allowed = False
                    End If
                End If
                'Avoid pasting in Readonly columns
                If MyDataGridview.Rows(Y).Cells(X).ReadOnly Then
                    Allowed = False
                End If
                If Allowed Then
                    MyDataGridview.Rows(Y).Cells(X).Value = OriginValue(i-ii*m1)
                    End If                                  
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub

Private Function SelectedAreaMinRow(MyDataGridView As DataGridView) As Integer
    Dim minRowIndex As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count - 1
        If i = 0 Then
            minRowIndex = MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex
        End If
        minRowIndex = Math.Min(MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex, minRowIndex)
    Next i

    Return minRowIndex
End Function

Private Function SelectedAreaMinColumn(MyDataGridView As DataGridView) As Integer
    Dim minColumnIndex As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count - 1
        If i = 0 Then
            minColumnIndex = MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).ColumnIndex
        End If
        minColumnIndex = Math.Min(MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).ColumnIndex, minColumnIndex)
    Next i

    Return minColumnIndex
End Function

Private Function SelectedAreaRows(MyDataGridView As DataGridView) As Integer
    Dim minRowIndex As Integer
    Dim MaxRowIndex As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count - 1
        If i = 0 Then
            minRowIndex = MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex
            MaxRowIndex = MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex
        End If
        minRowIndex = Math.Min(MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex, minRowIndex)
        MaxRowIndex = Math.Max(MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex, MaxRowIndex)
    Next i

    Return MaxRowIndex-minRowIndex+1
End Function

Private Function SelectedAreaColumns(MyDataGridView As DataGridView) As Integer
    Dim minColumnIndex As Integer
    Dim MaxColumnIndex As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count - 1
        If i = 0 Then
            minColumnIndex = MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).ColumnIndex
            MaxColumnIndex = MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).ColumnIndex
        End If
        minColumnIndex = Math.Min(MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).ColumnIndex, minColumnIndex)
        MaxColumnIndex = Math.Max(MyDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).ColumnIndex, MaxColumnIndex)
    Next i

    Return MaxColumnIndex-minColumnIndex+1
End Function
```